# Failed to find provider info Android

Tags: java, android

Having a weird issue with android where it can't find the path to my content provider.

Here is my manifest & code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="beaudoin.jonathan.provider.edu"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="beaudoin.jonathan.provider.edu.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:name=".MyProvider"
        android:authorities="beaudoin.jonathan.provider.edu.MyProvider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:multiprocess="true" >
    </provider>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the code

```
package beaudoin.jonathan.provider.edu;

import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;

public class MyProvider extends ContentProvider {
    static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "beaudoin.jonathan.provider.edu.MyProvider"; // use your own path please
    static final String URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/cte";
    static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);
    static final String id = "id";
    static final String name = "name";
    static final int uriCode = 1;
    static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
    private static HashMap<String, String> values;
    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "cte", uriCode);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "cte/*", uriCode);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int count = 0;
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case uriCode:
                count = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs); break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case uriCode:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/cte";
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        System.out.println(URL);
        long rowID = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", values);
        if (rowID > 0) {
            Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
            return _uri;
        }
        throw new SQLException("Failed to add a record into " + uri);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        Context context = getContext();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        if (db != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        qb.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case uriCode:
                qb.setProjectionMap(values);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }
        if (sortOrder == null || sortOrder == "") {
            sortOrder = name;
        }
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null,
                null, sortOrder);
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                      String[] selectionArgs) {
        int count = 0;
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case uriCode:
                count = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return count;
    }

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
    static final String TABLE_NAME = "names";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
            + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + " name TEXT NOT NULL);";

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is where I load my provider.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    cursorLoader= new CursorLoader(this, Uri.parse("content://beaudoin.jonathan.provider.edu.MyProvider/cte"), null, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
11-18 19:28:45.643 13969-14269/beaudoin.jonathan.provider.edu E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for beaudoin.jonathan.provider.edu.MyProvider
```

I've went through each class and manifest to make sure the package names match exactly but I'm still having the issue.

Comment: Why not call the content provider directly by the  url property  e.g `MyProvider.CONTENT_URI` it should be declared as  public final static.

Comment: The onCreateLoader method is in a separate project.

Comment: have you tried to access your content provider in the same project?

Comment: Yes, it works fine within the same project.

Comment: Try manually uninstall the application from where you try to access your provider and install again.

Comment: And also try add this line  `<grant-uri-permission android:pathPattern=".*" />` inside your provider manifest e.g `<provider>...   <grant-uri-permission android:pathPattern=".*" /> </provider>`

Comment: Perhaps will not solve your problem, but the answer to this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790845/multiprocess-content-providers-synced-to-default-one) explains that the `multiprocess` attribute for a provider should not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what happened but it starting working when I ran the projects on my home pc.

Comment: as I mentioned in the comments. You should have tried MANUALLY uninstall apk which uses content ptovider and install it again.